# Redux and Calendar repeating events

Tags: json, events, calendar, redux, repeat

What should be the proper way of storing / handling repeating events in the redux store ?

Problem: Let's say that we have a backend API that generates repeating events trough a complicated business logic.Some of the events might have the same ID. Lets say that generated output looks this way :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Weekly meeting",
    "all_day": true,
    "starts_at": "2017-09-12",
    "ends_at": "2017-09-12"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Daily meeting1",
    "all_day": false,
    "starts_at": "2017-09-12",
    "ends_at": "2017-09-12",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Daily meeting1",
    "all_day": false,
    "starts_at": "2017-09-13",
    "ends_at": "2017-09-13",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Daily meeting1",
    "all_day": false,
    "starts_at": "2017-09-14",
    "ends_at": "2017-09-14",
  }
]
```

Possible solution would be: generate unique ID by having additional property uid composed like this: `id + # + starts_at`. This way we could identify each occurrence uniquely. (I'm using this right now)

**Example**:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "uid": "1#2017-09-12",
    "title": "Weekly meeting",
    "all_day": true,
    "starts_at": "2017-09-12",
    "ends_at": "2017-09-12"
  }
]
```

I'm wondering is there some other way, maybe more elegant than having composed unique id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end this is what I've implemented (for demonstration purpose only - unrelated code is omitted):

eventRoot.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import ranges from './events'
import ids from './ids'
import params from './params'
import total from './total'

export default resource =>
  combineReducers({
    ids: ids(resource),
    ranges: ranges(resource),
    params: params(resource)
  })
```

events.js:

```
import { GET_EVENTS_SUCCESS } from '@/state/types/data'

export default resource => (previousState = {}, { type, payload, requestPayload, meta }) => {
  if (!meta || meta.resource !== resource) {
    return previousState
  }
  switch (type) {
    case GET_EVENTS_SUCCESS:
      const newState = Object.assign({}, previousState)
      payload.data[resource].forEach(record => {
        // ISO 8601 time interval string -
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals
        const range = record.start + '/' + record.end
        if (newState[record.id]) {
          if (!newState[record.id].includes(range)) {
            // Don't mutate previous state, object assign is only a shallow copy
            // Create new array with added id
            newState[record.id] = [...newState[record.id], range]
          }
        } else {
          newState[record.id] = [range]
        }
      })
      return newState
    default:
      return previousState
  }
}
```

There is also a data reducer but it's linked in parent reducer due to generic implementation that is re-used for common list responses. Events data are updated and start/end property is removed as it's composed by range ([ISO 8601 time interval string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals)). This can be later used by moment.range or split by '/' to get start/end data. I've opted for array of range strings to simplify checking of existing ranges, as they might grow large. I think that primitive string comparison (indexOf or es6 includes) would be faster than looping over complex structure in such cases.

data.js (stripped down version):

```
import { END } from '@/state/types/fetch'
import { GET_EVENTS } from '@/state/types/data'

const cacheDuration = 10 * 60 * 1000 // ten minutes
const addRecords = (newRecords = [], oldRecords, isEvent) => {
  // prepare new records and timestamp them
  const newRecordsById = newRecords.reduce((prev, record) => {
    if (isEvent) {
      const { start, end, ...rest } = record
      prev[record.id] = rest
    } else {
      prev[record.id] = record
    }
    return prev
  }, {})
  const now = new Date()
  const newRecordsFetchedAt = newRecords.reduce((prev, record) => {
    prev[record.id] = now
    return prev
  }, {})
  // remove outdated old records
  const latestValidDate = new Date()
  latestValidDate.setTime(latestValidDate.getTime() - cacheDuration)
  const oldValidRecordIds = oldRecords.fetchedAt
    ? Object.keys(oldRecords.fetchedAt).filter(id => oldRecords.fetchedAt[id] > latestValidDate)
    : []
  const oldValidRecords = oldValidRecordIds.reduce((prev, id) => {
    prev[id] = oldRecords[id]
    return prev
  }, {})
  const oldValidRecordsFetchedAt = oldValidRecordIds.reduce((prev, id) => {
    prev[id] = oldRecords.fetchedAt[id]
    return prev
  }, {})
  // combine old records and new records
  const records = {
    ...oldValidRecords,
    ...newRecordsById
  }
  Object.defineProperty(records, 'fetchedAt', {
    value: {
      ...oldValidRecordsFetchedAt,
      ...newRecordsFetchedAt
    }
  }) // non enumerable by default
  return records
}

const initialState = {}
Object.defineProperty(initialState, 'fetchedAt', { value: {} }) // non enumerable by default

export default resource => (previousState = initialState, { payload, meta }) => {
  if (!meta || meta.resource !== resource) {
    return previousState
  }
  if (!meta.fetchResponse || meta.fetchStatus !== END) {
    return previousState
  }
  switch (meta.fetchResponse) {
    case GET_EVENTS:
      return addRecords(payload.data[resource], previousState, true)
    default:
      return previousState
  }
}
```

This can be then used by an calendar component with event selector:

```
const convertDateTimeToDate = (datetime, timeZoneName) => {
  const m = moment.tz(datetime, timeZoneName)
  return new Date(m.year(), m.month(), m.date(), m.hour(), m.minute(), 0)
}

const compileEvents = (state, filter) => {
  const eventsRanges = state.events.list.ranges
  const events = []
  state.events.list.ids.forEach(id => {
    if (eventsRanges[id]) {
      eventsRanges[id].forEach(range => {
        const [start, end] = range.split('/').map(d => convertDateTimeToDate(d))
        // You can add an conditional push, filtered by start/end limits
        events.push(
          Object.assign({}, state.events.data[id], {
            start: start,
            end: end
          })
        )
      })
    }
  })
  return events
}
```

And here is how the data structure looks in the redux dev tools:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/5nzrG6e.png]

Each time the events are fetched, their data is updated (if there is a change) and references are added. Here is an screenshot of redux diff after fetching new events range:

[image]

Hope this helps somebody, I'll just add that this still isn't battle tested but more a proof of a concept that's working.

[EDIT] Btw. I'll probably move some of this logic to the backend as then there will be no need to split / join / delete properties.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possible pitfall with your current solution. What will happen if `id` and `start_id` of two events will be the same? Is it possible scenario in your domain?

Because of that I usually use [this nice lib](https://github.com/dylang/shortid) in such cases. It produces really short unique ids, which have some nice properties, like guaranties not to intersect, to be unpredictable and so on.

Also ask yourself if you actually need unique ids in your case. Looks like your back-end have no chance to distinguish events anyways, so why bother? Redux store will happily keep your events event without `uid`.

Comment: Well first of all thanks for the replay, it's good to hear other people opinions when troubleshooting things. If the `id` and `start_id` happen to be identical (in my case) I can tell it's the same event. Let's say you have 10 different student classes which are repeating daily. In my case I've opted for dynamic MM table that get's populated when subscription is added. Until that point events are presented dynamically. This way I don't pollute DB with entries/relations that are void. Other option would be to create an record for each event occurrence (and that might take a while for clients)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not much of an improvement (if at all) but just using `JSON.stringify` to check for duplicates could make unique id's obsolete.

```js
const existingEvents = [
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Daily meeting1",
    "all_day": false,
    "starts_at": "2017-09-14",
    "ends_at": "2017-09-14",
  }
];

const duplicate = {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Daily meeting1",
    "all_day": false,
    "starts_at": "2017-09-14",
    "ends_at": "2017-09-14",
};

const eventIsDuplicate = (existingEvents, newEvent) => {
    const duplicate = 
    existingEvents.find(event => JSON.stringify(event) == JSON.stringify(newEvent));
    return typeof duplicate != 'undefined';
};

console.log(eventIsDuplicate(existingEvents, duplicate)); // true
```

I guess this would only be preferable to your existing solution if, for some reason, you'd want to keep all the uniqueness logic on the client side.

Comment: Well the point isn't in preserve the uniqueness as much as properly handle the data in store and having maybe a normalized data that could be used elsewhere by re-using the same UID. Having the composed key works in my case, otherwise
 there is always an option to add ends_at to the composed key and that would make the event bullet proof even if the end date has changed (in my case those data is entirely equal .. only the start date is mutated)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the examples you've given, it seems like the server is sending a particular event whenever the details of the event change.

If that is so, and you want to track the changes to events, your might shape might be an array of objects with all the fields of the event that hold the current data, and a history property which is an array of all previous (or n most recent) event objects and the timestamps at which they were received. This is how your reducers would look, storing only the five most recent event changes for each event. I'm expecting the action to have a `payload` property which has your standard `event` property and a timestamp property, which can be easily accomplished in the action creator.

```
const event = (state = { history: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'EVENT_FETCHED':
      return ({
        ...action.payload.event,
        history: [...state.history, action.payload].slice(-5),
      });
    default:
      return state;
    }
  };


const events = (state = { byID: {}, IDs: [] }, action) => {
  const id = action.payload.event.ID;
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'EVENT_FETCHED':
      return id in state.byID
        ? {
          ...state,
          byID: { ...state.byID, [id]: event(state.byID[id], action) },
        }
        : {
          byID: { ...state.byID, [id]: event(undefined, action) },
          IDs: [id],
        };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Doing this, you don't need any unique ID. Please let me know if I have misunderstood your problem.

Edit: This is a slight extension of the [pattern](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) in the Redux documentation, to store previous events.

Comment: Thing is that I need to preserve starts_at which differs for some events with same ID (everything else is the same). Your implementation just collects all the events as separated arrays. Normalization should be done in such a way that by using an ID (or UID) you could get exact event and re-use it for some other parts of the code.  My implementation already works, so it's not a question of making it works but more how to optimize it and what are the standards for this cases (if they exists).

Comment: And when an event data changes (anything but start_at), the change should be propagated  to all events with the same ID.